# How to add vars in response data from API

Tags: python, api, rest

I have a function that accepts variables and i need to pass the test, there is a condition in test that all the vars for the function CAN BE found in response data from API.

So how can i add variables to the api, i searched in local files and looked through the api documentation. There are no functions for adding variables or can add me.

test function:

```
def test_variables_and_functions_for_formulas_exist(connector):
    """Test variables and functions for formula.

    Make sure all the vars for the formulas CAN BE found in response data from API.
    """
    formulas = {
        field["id"]: field["formula"]
        for field in field_lists[connector]
        if field.get("formula") is not None
    }

    field_response_names = {
        field.get("upstream_api_response_name", field["id"])
        for field in field_lists[connector]
    }

    # field upstream API name in a formula can be combined with a table
    # (endpoint) name if the former is unique not per field list but per table
    table_field_response_names = {
        (f"{field.get('table')}_{field.get('upstream_api_response_name', field['id'])}")
        for field in field_lists[connector]
        if field.get("table") is not None
    }

    formula_parser = py_expression_eval.Parser()
    formula_parser.functions = dict(formula_parser.functions, **FORMULA_FUNCTIONS)

    for field, formula_definition in formulas.items():

        formula = formula_parser.parse(formula_definition)
        formula_vars = formula.variables()
        non_existent_vars = list(
            set(formula_vars) - field_response_names - table_field_response_names
        )

        assert len(non_existent_vars) == 0, (
            f"Names {non_existent_vars} for field {field} are missing from "
            "the lists of upstream_api_response_name's and available functions"
        )
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the code language you're using.

Comment: @devlincarnate ok, python